# (Mac OS X, Cocoa) How to make drag-and-droppable placeholder elements in an input text field?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm writing a Cocoa app where I would like the user to be able to put together a template string using placeholders.  (For example, an (artist) placeholder would be filled in by the artist of the song currently playing in iTunes, etc.)  I've seen apps that do something like this where each possible placeholder term is displayed in a blue "lozenge," and the user can drag and drop these "lozenges" into an input text field to construct a string, optionally entering some custom text of their own (e.g. separating (artist) and (title) "lozenges" with a hyphen).

Does anyone know if there is any sample code anywhere that will help me implement something like this?

I'm talking about something like this: (this comes from the "Hazel" app where, in a Hazel rule, you can rename a file based on a template pattern you specify)

[image: drag-and-dropable placeholder elements in an input text field]

Comment: Those "blue lozenges" are NSTokenFields, so go check out the Token Field Programming Guide.

Answer (score 5):

NSTokenField is focused in the above pic (has the blue ring around it). Each "token" (your lozenges) is an auto-recognized string for the token field. As rdelmar comments above, read up on NSTokenField and you'll be most of the way there.

The "source" of tokens is likely a rounded-edged NSBox containing lined-up borderless, no-background NSTokenFields with one token each. That'll give you easy drag-and-drop as well as easy alignment.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to customize the l&f of the individual tokens, you need to implement your own stuff: NSTextView with NSTextAttachment which have NSTextAttachmentCells... Its painful and a lot of code but actually not that hard

The NSTokenAttachment cell only has lots of private l&f options :(